# Soap UI Pro missing requests after Composite Project

Tags: soapui, ready-api

[image]I did project composite and after that I got this Resolve Project window where I need to add some WADL file. I don't know from where I should get it? I got Missing WADL file description error also , Resolve source property error, resolve target error. After I pressed OK when this window appeared I have lack of some request in my project also when I had XML before composite I have 21 requests for BOT_ANNOUNCEMENTS but after the composite some of them are gone. But before I opening the new composite project using 'Import Composite Project' I got this pop ups 'Missing REST Resources for Request' and after several click of OK button when I open BOT_ANNOUNCEMENTS my requests list is looking like this.

I see that in first two I need to add proper WADL file path but on the rest I don't know what going on and which option choose from drop down.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this most often when the underlying webservice has changed in some way, for example services added or deleted or refactored in some way. SoapUI Pro is asking you to reconfirm what the properties in your existing project map to in the newly-detected WADL.

I've never found this manual resolution process to work perfectly and I burn time trying to find and fix errors. One option is just to import the WADL again in a fresh soapUI project and copy your test cases across.